# In JSP replacing the null value retrived from mysql database with "N/A"

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am using jsp and in result of query i have have row whose value is NULL in mysql database
i want to replace with N/A

```
 String check1=null;
    while (rs.next())
{
    check1=rs.getString("l.country");

    if(check1.equals(null))
    {
    check1="N/A";
    }
    outfile.write("rs.getString(check1)");

}
```

but i "N/A" is not display 
Please tell me where i have made the mistake.

Comment: what are you trying to do with "outfile.write(..."?  Are you just trying to output what's in check1?  If so, just do outfile.write(check1);

Comment: i am writing value of check to xml file but its not getting written in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this in your SQL query you know. Example

```
select IFNULL(country, 'N/A') from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

following will only work if you want to compare values in string not null:

```
if(check1.equals(null))
```

change it to:

```
if(check1 == null)
```